# How to send a payload/message in private channel with Laravel / Pusher / Echo

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pusher

I'm about to go mad after spending the last 5 hours trying to figure this out and I could **really** use some help.

What I want to achieve is to be able to send a status-message to the client in some form. It's not important what kind of message as long as I can read it and understand the message on the client. I'm dispatching three jobs to a queue in Laravel and I would like to use the Event class to relay a message to the client along the way to let him/her know how far we've come.

At the moment I can send a message to the client, the private channel is working and so far so good, but the only thing I manage to send is the user-object. Which is not helpful at all.

**bootstrap.js**:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxx',
    cluster: 'eu',
    forceTLS: true
});

var channel = window.Echo.private('user.'+ window.Laravel.user); // 
channel.listen('.status', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

**DeployStatus.php**:

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class DeployStatus implements ShouldBroadcast
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

  public $user;

  public function __construct($user)
  {
      $this->user = $user;
  }

  public function broadcastOn()
  {
      return new PrivateChannel('user.'.$this->user->id);
  }

  public function broadcastAs()
  {
      return 'status';
  }

  public function broadcastWith()
  {
      return ['id' => $this->user->id];
  }
}
```

(I tried with the broadcastWith() method, but no effect)

And the last one **DeploySite.php**:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Events\DeployStatus;

class DeploySite implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $user = auth()->user();
        event(new DeployStatus($user));
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: `broadcastWith` certainly works. I am currently using it in my project. Try stopping your project completely, run `optimize:clear` and `php artisan serve` again. Also what is the result of `JSON.stringify(data)`? could your try consoling just the data?

Comment: @UzairRiaz Oh man. That is 5 hours of my live I'm never getting back. `optimize:clear` solved it. Thank you very very much! I was about to throw my computer out the window..

Comment: no problem, I have been there so I knew what to do. I'll post it as an answer and you can mark it so it helps the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`broadcastWith()` certainly works. I am currently using it in my project. Try stopping your project completely, run `php artisan optimize:clear` and `php artisan serve` again.